# How to filter products on react js

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm studying the reaction, and I'm trying to filter by manufacturer the products that I previously request via the API. With this code, products are displayed, and then you can filter by manufacturer. However, when you try to filter them again, i.e. select products from a different manufacturer, nothing happens.
My code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import Loader from './../Loader/Loader'
import ProductItem from './ProductItem'

function Catalog() {
    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])
    const [brands, setBrands] = React.useState([])
    const [brand, setBrand] = React.useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
const url = 'https://avtodoka-msk.ru/aimylogic-mission.json'
fetch(proxyUrl + url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(products => {
        setProducts(products)
        const brands = []
        products.map(product => {
            return(
                brands.push(...product.brend)
            )
        })
        setBrands([...new Set(brands)])
    })
}, [])

 function toggleBrand(e) {
    setBrand(e.target.value)

    setProducts(
        products.filter(product => {
            if ([...product.brend].includes(e.target.value)) {
                return true
            }
        })
    )

}






return (
    <div className="container pt-5">

        {brands.length ? (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <select value={brand} onChange={toggleBrand}>
                        <option value={''}>Выбрать бренд</option>

                        {brands.map((brend,index) => {
                            return(
                                <option value={brend} key={index}>{brend}</option>
                            )
                        })}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        ): null}        
        {products.length ? (

            <div className="row">

                {products.map(product => {
                    return (

                        <ProductItem 
                            key={product.id}
                            product={product}
                        />
                    )
                })}


            </div>
        ) :  <Loader />}
    </div>
)
}

export default Catalog
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your state needs to have:

- `products` array - containing your products.
- `brands` array - containing your manufacturers.
- `brand` array - containing an active filter by manufacturer.

If that is correct, then I see a couple of problems with your code:

1. You're overcomplicating your array methods, leading to wanted behaviors.
2. Now, the real problem here is that when you filter the first time, you lose access to all the products, and therefore you need to re-fetch them on every filter click.

Giving that, here's your updated code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import Loader from './../Loader/Loader'
import ProductItem from './ProductItem'

function Catalog() {
    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])
    const [brands, setBrands] = React.useState([])
    const [brand, setBrand] = React.useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
        const url = 'https://avtodoka-msk.ru/aimylogic-mission.json'     
        fetch(proxyUrl + URL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(products => {
                if (brands.length <= 0) 
                    setBrandsFromProducs(products)

                const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => !brand || product.brend.includes(brand))
                setProducts(filteredProducts)
            })
    }, [brand])

    function setBrandsFromProducs(products) {
        const brands = products.reduce(
            (acc, product) => ([...acc, ...product.brend])
        , [])
        setBrands([...new Set(brands)])
    }

    function toggleBrand(e) {
        const selectedBrand = e.target.value
        setBrand(selectedBrand)
    }

}
```

**Key aspects:**

1. `product.brend` is an array. To extract all the brands from this JSON, you need to flatten an array of arrays, therefore you're reducing it into a flat array - hence the usage of a [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). You only need to do this if the `brands` array is empty. However, if you're not concerned about performance you can remove the `if` statement to always reset the `brands`array.
2. Your event is selecting the brand, it shouldn't contain any other side-effect (filtering the products). Those should live inside a proper scope -> `useEffect`. To trigger this event, you need to 'listen' to changes to the `brand` filter, therefore it needs to be specified as a dependency of the `useEffect`.
3. Your `filter` was missing the `return false` outside the `if` statement. However, it could be simplified because [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) returns a boolean value and doesn't mutate the original array. The filter I created will first check if you have an active filter and only filter if you do have one.
4. You need to make sure that `e.target.value` is the exact string from the `product.brend`'s array.

**Small suggestions:**

1. If you control the API, your filters should always be on the backend side to avoid bigger payloads than you need.
2. If you don't use the `brand` state, you can safely remove it. Without your JSX I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks. Json – https://avtodoka-msk.ru/aimylogic-mission.json, product.brand value is array.

Comment: I see, please, update your question with a simplified sample, since your data is way too big in that son to be easily read.